# hbase read the data is not large, but the disk io amount is very large

Tags: hadoop, io, hbase

VERSION : hbase-1.2.0-cdh-5.10.0

hbase read the data is not large, but the disk io amount is very large? 
 and my cluster is deployed on the virtual machine, is it related?[IOTOP of Hbase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5FxZ.png)

I didn't initiate the scan operation, but I use jstack to view the region server progress, I see this [jstack info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8ROH.png)

Comment: would be useful to see what operations do you perform? scans? what kind of scans?

Comment: Could you define not large and very large in units (KB, MB, GB)?